# Untrusted char pointer arguments

Tags: c, security, buffer-overflow

What's considered best practice for handling what's **meant** to be a string as
an argument to a function ie

```
int use_the_force(const char *dark_side_file_name) {
  char *safe_force_it_is = Yoda(dark_side_file_name);
  return useTheForceYouCan(safe_force_it_is);
}
```

Assuming the caller is Darth Vader, what would Yoda do in order to ensure that when we use things like strlen/strnlen or memchr on "safe_force_it_is" that there's a NULL terminator and that we're not running off into the dark side when we use what we're expecting to be a valid **string**?

Comment: There's little you can do. Unless you have some notion of "maximum expected string length".

Comment: That said, what is a (realistic) scenario where this would be an issue? I.e. if you're in a situation where malicious code is calling your code, surely you already have problems?

Answer (score 5):

It's not reasonable to take a string of unknown length and try to figure out if it is null terminated or not.  If it's not, how would you know when to stop?

There may be a handful of crazy, non-portable ideas, but none of them is required in a sane program.  You need to know that the input is null-terminated, or else you need to know its maximum length.

Comment: I know the it's unreasonable to ask, "How long's a piece of string?". If that's how the question came across then I worded it badly. To me, getting a file path and doing malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(path) + 1); seems foolhardy when I don't trust the caller. PATH_MAX has issues, see, [PATH_MAX simply isn't](http://insanecoding.blogspot.com/2007/11/pathmax-simply-isnt.html). When I read that I should check my inputs ie [API00-C](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/API00-C.+Functions+should+validate+their+parameters) I'm still left wondering what would Yoda do?

Comment: You just have to use strlen.  If you can't trust that the char* you're given is even a null-terminated string, then you need to redesign.